# How I can implement Login / Logout Navigation using UserDefaults in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

**[image: strong text]**Every time when I run the app I have to do the login to enter the home page of the app.

How can I store the session  when I tap the login button untill I Tap the logout button.

So, that I can avoid the login everytime when I run my application.

Please help me out......

Other solutions are not working.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginName: UITextField!

   @IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {

  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")

        if loginName.text == "test" && password.text == "test" {

            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
            Switcher.updateRootVC()

        }
        else{
            print("Invalid credentials")
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")
    Switcher.updateRootVC()

    }

}
```

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


  var window: UIWindow?

    func loadBaseController() {
       let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       guard let window = self.window else { return }
       window.makeKeyAndVisible()
       if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") == false {
           let loginVC: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! ViewController
           self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
       } else {
           let homeVC: HomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showData") as! HomeViewController
           let navigationHomeVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
           self.window?.rootViewController = navigationHomeVC
       }
      self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

       self.loadBaseController()

        return true

    }
}
```

I referred the same method  of this link   https://medium.com/@paul.allies/ios-swift4-login-logout-branching-4cdbc1f51e2c but it is not useful because I'm getting not the expected result .
I'm the correct status code but not the correct view controller.
Please help me out to solve this problem........

In the given link it is adding the `TabbarVc` to the tabor

Comment: Check your isLoggedIn value in the Appdelegate and present your controller from the Appdelegate file. In Appdelegate file you want to set your rootView controller.

Comment: Ok. l'll check it

Comment: I checked , but I dont know where to set the value ```isLoggedIn``` in app delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 11 there are 2 file while we create a new project so if you want to change rootViewController from the delegate file then you need to load that controller from the **SceneDelegate.swift** file.

```
//SceneDelegate.swift

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene

    self.loadBaseController()
}


func loadBaseController() {
   let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   guard let window = self.window else { return }
   window.makeKeyAndVisible()
   if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn") == false {
       let loginVC: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! ViewController
       self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
   } else {
       let homeVC: HomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showData") as! HomeViewController
       let navigationHomeVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
       self.window?.rootViewController = navigationHomeVC
   }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201144/discussion-on-answer-by-rushabh-shah-change-rootviewcontroller-from-the-appdeleg).

Comment: ```SceneDelegate.swift``` I don't have this file.... my project was created in Xcode 11 last week I just updated my xcode

Comment: check my updated code that I tried by referring the medium link    https://medium.com/@paul.allies/ios-swift4-login-logout-branching-4cdbc1f51e2c        but still not getting answer ....

Comment: Can I add this same code in AppDelegate.swift , because I created the project in the xcode10 . When I created the demo this works for me

Comment: When I tried in my real application then my application crashes

Comment: Yes, But in Appdelegate code will be changed. So please be sure in which Xcode do you want to develop your application.

Comment: what I should  do  if I want to show the tab bar's view controller[0] ? @RushabhShah

Comment: Didn't get you can you please explain in detail?

Comment: After logged in for 1st time .Every time I want to open the tabbar's  viewcontroller at 0 index i.e ```myHomePageVC```

Comment: I hope your root view controller is your Tabbar Controller then you need to just write down below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

`let myTabBar = self.window.rootViewController as! UITabBarController // Getting Tab Bar
    myTabBar.selectedIndex = 0 //Selecting tab here
    return true`

Comment: Actually I'm having the same UIDesign as image shown in the  question , Now will you help me for the solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202196/discussion-between-rushabh-shah-and-patel123).

Comment: @RushabhShah - I have used same code for setting rootview controller. How to perform logout in such case. I have tried removing user defaults and set root to LoginVC but it doesn't moves to Login Screen

Answer (score 1):

You Have to use SceneDelegate to solve this as said in previous comment.
But if you still want to use Switcher Class to do this.
Here is the solution: 
[Add-> private(set) static var shared: SceneDelegate? and Self.shared = self
        Switcher.updateRootVC()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxsUj.jpg)

after adding those lines.
now edit the Switcher class like this:

[Modify the switcher class like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfvBW.jpg)

now you can Switch from anywhere using switcher class..