# Running ios simulator shows black screen

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie trying to learn ios programming.

So, I have Xcode 11.1
I deleted the main story board.

My AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()  //UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    return true
}
```

My ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }


}
```

I removed the references of main from project settings and Info.plist

But, when I try to run the app, the ios simulator shows a black screen

If it helps, trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xv1mJvwXok&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj

Comment: Here it is answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/change-rootviewcontroller-from-the-appdelegate-based-on-login-session/58444613?noredirect=1#comment103292323_58444613

Comment: @RushabhShah: Yep yep.. that fixes it

Comment: Great happy to hear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change rootViewController from the AppDelegate based on Login session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/change-rootviewcontroller-from-the-appdelegate-based-on-login-session)