# `iOS 13.1.3 update` - Got a black screen right after launch screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, launch-screen

When i run my app using xCode 11 Swift 5 on a device that have installed latest update i.e **13.1.3** its become empty a pure **black screen** following launch screen.

There is nothing in debug hierarchy but view controller is working fine `viewDidLoad()`  `viewWillAppear()` working all fine.

It's though working fine for 13.1.2 and older versions.

Comment: Are you creating your project in Xcode 11?

Comment: Yes, it's in xCode 11

Comment: see how you are initialising your initial view controller.

Comment: @xhobi Check this one it might be help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/change-rootviewcontroller-from-the-appdelegate-based-on-login-session

Comment: initiate first storyboard at _General -> Deployment info -> Main interface_ and at that storyboard I've make a controller as initial controller.

Weird thing is that it's working hell fine for **13.1.2** and older one's but not for **13.1.3**.

Comment: Have you set Rootview Controller from the AppDelegate file?

Comment: @RushabhShah Thanks for your concern but that didn't work for me. Cause i believe it has nothing to do with AppDelegate Plus my controller working fine, i can have the access to `viewDidLoad()` `viewWillAppear()` inside my initial controller.

Comment: I am stuck with this problem too, but my problem is when i generate the release in testflight. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/390323#390323

Comment: Issue has been resolved looks like `UIApplicationSceneManifest` this key in info.plist causing that issue. I just remove this key and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue has been resolved looks like `UIApplicationSceneManifest` this key in info.plist causing that issue. I just remove this key and now it's working fine.