# Presenting different UIViewController on the app Launch

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to present different `UIViewController` on the launch of my app. I have a "login" page for the user to interact with. Once the user logs in or creates an account it takes to a different `UIViewController` with a map to interact with. I've looked online and so far I know that we should do it within `AppDelegate.swift` file. I have not completed the statement whether or not the user has logged in since I am still running into some errors

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2.0)

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = MainNavigationContoller()

    return true
}
```

I also have another swift file with **MainNavigationContoller** that should call the mainviewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let isloggedIn = false

    if isloggedIn == false {
        self.present(mainViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.present(mapViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
}
```

The app launches with the launchScreen but then sends errors to mainViewController such as *Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value*

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/how-i-can-implement-login-logout-navigation-using-userdefaults-in-swift/58444613#58444613

Comment: Do you get this error in your `MainNavigationContoller` ?

Comment: are you using storyboards? are you initialising the mainViewController and mapViewController properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating the View Controllers properly.

Here is a function that I use to make a root view controller, put this into your AppDelegate.

```
  func makeRootVC(storyBoardName : String, vcName : String) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
    let duration: TimeInterval = 0.6
    UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: duration, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
}
```

Now in your Appdelegate, replace your code with this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2.0)

self.makeRootVC(storyboardName: "Main", vcName : "YourVCStoryboardId")
return true
```

}

and in your MainNavigationController,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let isloggedIn = false
let appDelegateObj = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

if isloggedIn == false {
    appDelegateObj.makeRootVC(storyboardName: "Main", vcName: "mainViewController") 
} else {
    appDelegateObj.makeRootVC(storyboardName: "Main", vcName: "mapViewController") 
}
```

}

NOTE: Open storyboard and give every controller a StoryboardID. What I prefer is naming them the same as ViewController's name as it is easy to remember. and in vcName, we need to pass the storyboarID of the controller we want to present.

UPDATE:

Above code is for making a root view controller, if you want to push controllers, you can use this code instead:

```
extension UIViewController {

func pushVC(storyboardName : String, vcname : String)  {
       let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcname)
       vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }
```

}

In your MainNavigationController if instead of making root view controllers in viewDidLoad, you want to just push the controller, then use the above code like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let isloggedIn = false

if isloggedIn == false {
    self.pushVC(storyboardName: "Main", vcName: "mainViewController") 
} else {
    self.pushVC(storyboardName: "Main", vcName: "mapViewController") 
}
```

}

Comment: I am getting ***Thread 1: signal SIGABRT*** when running UPDATE code. The problem is in the function `func pushVC`. My file names includes `Main.storyboard` and `mainViewController.swift` which I believe i should be using

Comment: I am getting a ***Thread 1: signal SIGABRT***  when I put breakpoints on AppDelegate I notice its on `self.makeRootVC(storyBoardName: "Main", vcName : "mainViewController")` This is on the first option

Comment: Thank you sir, I had to add the identifier to the Storyboard

Comment: @MaxBojorquez happy to help :) Please accept the answer too.