# Firebase IOS Google Sign in: Change views after successfully signed in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to build my first IOS App and trying to implement Firebase Google sign-in following the documentation located here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin. The issue is trying to change views if a user has successfully signed in. I have tried several solutions regarding this problem from other Stack overflow posts with none seeming to work. I believe this is because of the new sceneDelegate file which the other solutions don't have to take into account as they're using previous versions of XCode.

The Google sign-in is implemented in the App Delegate and the specific code that actually tries to authenticate a user (In the App delegate) is here:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
  // ...
  if let error = error {
    // ...
    return
  }

  guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
  let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                    accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
  if let error = error {
    // ...
    return
  }
  // User is signed in
  // Here i want to change views
}

}
```

Once the user is signed in how do I change views? I have tried everything I can find and everything seems to not work or crash the app.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to change login screen to main screen of app?

Comment: Yes, I am. Login screen to another view (Home view)

Comment: You can also write it in the `LoginVC`. From there you can check when the user is signed in and then, `self.navigationController.pushViewController(nextVC(),animated: true)`

Comment: @Rob what would be the best way to check if the user has signed in from my view controller?

Comment: I'll show you in 11-12 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, how can you do it in your `LoginVC`:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self

  }
}
```

This is what I have added in the `viewDidLoad` method. After that, I have created a custom button which inherits to `UIButton`. I have created that button programmatically but you can just use `@IBOutlet weak var googleB: UIButton!`. Then, on that button's tap, you can add this:

```
@IBAction func googleBTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Then, I have created the `extension` for `GIDSignInDelegate`.

```
extension LoginViewController: GIDSignInDelegate {

 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {

        print(error)

        return
    }

    guard let email = user.profile.email else { return }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

      let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
  Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
    if let error = error {
     print(error)
      return
    }

    //If login is successful then add
   self.navigationController.pushViewController(nextVC(), animated: true) 
   //OR
   self.performSegue() //<-- Whatever goes in here, I don't use these methods as I create views programitacally, but you can use it here and move to next view 
}

 }

}
```

Well, this is one way, but as your app goes bigger it is better to create a `FirebaseHelper` class and you are going to use a lot of common methods like `fetchProviders`, `signIn` for `Google`, `Facebook`, `Apple` sign-ins. So, you can write one function which can fetch the credential and log in the user, that will be optimized then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your SignIn function in the AppDelegate:

```
let nextVC= UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
window?.rootViewController = nextVC
```

Answer (score 0):

First you set your segue from `LoginViewController`to `HomeViewController` and set identifier for your segue to `loginToHome`.

```
            if error == nil {
                print("User signed in")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self)
            }
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get an error saying "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'performSegue'" and "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'showStatusLine'"

Comment: You do not need add `showStatusLine`. You should add your login screen codes to your `LoginViewController` not in your `AppDelegate`. After you should search for segue in google. You can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/how-i-can-implement-login-logout-navigation-using-userdefaults-in-swift

Comment: Google authentication is in the App Delegate. How do I check if a user has signed in, in the view controller if the 'performSegue' is there?

Comment: You understand if user is signed in or not signed in with `if let error = error` or `if error == nil` so if error is nil mean you signed in successfully and performSegue to HomeViewController

Comment: yes, I understand the errors but they're in the app delegate inside the sign function which has to stay in the app delegate. So if error == nil and the user is signed in how do I then call a perform segue in the view controller?

Comment: best explanation is here: https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-root-controller-navigation-3625eedbbff