# Access ViewController from AppDelegate in Xcode 11.5 (firebase google sign in)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, appdelegate

I'm implementing Firebase Google Sign in for a toy app. After Google sign in, the app suppose to move from SignInViewController to HomePageViewController. According the firebase instructions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin), 
1. GDSignInButton is installed in SignInViewController
2. AppDelegate should implement sign() of GDSignInDelegate.

Before the end of sign(), which is in AppDelegate, how should I tell SignInViewController that, you can move to HomePageViewController. I have successfully followed the instructions and finished sign in. But I don't know how to transition the view controllers in AppDelegate.

Note that, in Xcode 11.5, there is a SceneDelegate, which owns a window that used to belong to AppDelegate in older version. So we can't get the reference to a Window, which contains view controllers, in AppDelegate. Thanks in advance!

#### My problem is solved. Thanks to those who helped! But my question remains: Imagine you are in AppDelegate, how do you communicate with (access) your views?

Comment: It works even if you do not add it to `AppDelegate` and keep it in `SignInVC`.

Comment: Hi Rob, you are right. I'm a newbie, trying to strictly follow the firebase instructions.

Comment: Hi Rob, I just found your answer to another similar question. In your suggestion, you have the following. 

@IBAction func googleBTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

I have a question,

Comment: Please ignore my previous question. Here is the one I would like to ask you. 
In your suggestion, you mentioned you would use FirebaseHelper class to pack relevant firebase functions. Would you mind listing a high-level structure about this FirebaseHelper class? I would like to see how you put various third-part libraries into a class. That sounds like a very neat way to code. Thanks! Below is the post you answered: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598468/firebase-ios-google-sign-in-change-views-after-successfully-signed-in?rq=1

Comment: As you said you are a beginner, a lot of beginners copy and paste code use the same methods in different classes without realising that it can be a havoc tomorrow. For eg: You have a `function abc()` and you have copied and pasted it in 20 other classes and if after 2 months you are asked/need to change anything that in the function then you have to change it across those 20 pages. So, the better way is to create an `Extension` or a `Helper` class and call the functions from there.

Comment: Thanks Rob! I checked out a YouTube video on Helper class. Now the sharedInstance makes sense to me (having seen it multiple times, was wondering why it is that way).  
One more question I will stop. The tutorials I followed are mostly chopped pieces and casual. (Youtubers often say, "normally I wouldn't do this, but it's ok since this is a tutorial."). e.g., I never seen a Helper, which is a good way to code. Could you point me to a small-size sample project that is complete and with all these good ways of writing swift code? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I can show it to you in here, but I need to be it in the chat not here.

Comment: It seems that I can't create a chat room. Anyway, I don't want to waste your time anymore. I was just eager to know everything at once, which is not that realistic. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not to disappoint you here is a small example:

`class FirebaseHelper { 
private let authInstance = Auth().auth
    static let sharedInstance = FirebaseHelper() // Singleton Read about it

  func signIn(credential: AuthCredential) { 
     authInstance.signInWithCredential(credential: credential) { (response, error  in  
  if let error = error {. print error }
 if let response = response { print(response) }
)}
}
}`

Usage in `SignInVC`: 

`class SignInVC { 
   FirebaseHelper.sharedInstance.signIn(credential: Your Credential)
}`

Comment: Thank you Rob. It's a good example to follow and expand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code to do it in iOS 13:

### AppDelegate.swift

```
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    // configure de firebase app
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // other methods in app delegate

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
}
```

### SceneDelegate.swift

```
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseAuth

// conform to the google sign in delegate
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // when the app launches, it checks if the user is signed in, and redirect to the correct view controller
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // redirect to the home controller
                self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarController")
                self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            } else {
                // redirect to the login controller
                self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
                self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    }

    // handle the sign in to redirect to the home controller
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            // redirect the user to the home controller
            self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarController")
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...

    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you Danni! The google sign in functionality can be in other places than AppDelegate. I don't know why Firebase document has to place that functionality in the AppDelegate. I was just sticking too strictly to what the firebase document says.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses `SceneDelegate` then you must use the following code to get to the key window. From `keyWindow` you can get to rootViewController by using `.rootViewController` and down-cast it as `MyViewController` and access it accordingly.

```swift
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
let myViewContorller = keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MyViewController
```

Comment: Hi Rankenstein, Thanks for your help. For some reason, the myViewController is always nil, no matter what .activationState I tried.

Answer (score 0):

In appDelegate:-

It is possible by passing it as RootViewController

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
     let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let viewController : UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“InitialControllerID”) as InitialViewController
     self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
     self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

     return true
}
```

Or if rootViewController is of type UINavigation Controller then push your home screen over it like:-

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “InitialControllerID") as! InitialViewController
rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
return true
}
```

Or

On the basis of this article:- “https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-set-application-root-view-controller-programmatically-in-xcode-11/“

```
For iOS 13
In SceneDelegate.swift 

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options `connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {`

// If this scene's self.window is nil then set a new UIWindow object to it.
self.window = self.window ?? UIWindow()

// Set this scene's window's background color.
self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

// Create a ViewController object and set it as the scene's window's root view controller.
self.window!.rootViewController = ViewController()

// Make this scene's window be visible.
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

guard scene is UIWindowScene else { return }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Apps Maven!  Your first two methods do not work because it's iOS 13, where there is no window in AppDelegate.  I don't know how to implement the third method, because the sign in function ends in AppDelegate.