# How to dismiss all presented view controllers when user KILL the app?

Tags: swift

I am making a twitter-like app for assignment and have to make the app stay logged in until user log out.
I have "Login View Controller" which has a segue to "Home Table View Controller".

In my loginviewcontroller.swift, I have following code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userLoggenIn") == true{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self)
    }
}
```

After I login the app (making UserDefaults.standard.bool to be true and go to Home table view), I kill the app and re-open the app, but the viewDidAppear function is not called. I guess this is because the Home table view is not dismissed? How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to do this so please follow this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/how-i-can-implement-login-logout-navigation-using-userdefaults-in-swift/58444613#58444613

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to Use scene delegate method like

`func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) { }`

or

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) { }
```

like so you can save some data. I usually save Context for CoreData.